# Python; sklean; BaseEstimator; Argument error when using nested function

Tags: python, class, oop, scikit-learn

I want to wrap my Scipy optimizer into the BaseEstimator.
Here's my code

```
import numpy as np

from scipy.optimize import minimize

from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
from sklearn.base import RegressorMixin

class CLS_Estimator(BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin):
    def __init__(self, obj_func=None, x0=0, method='SLSQP'):
        # self.obj_func = obj_func
        self.x0 = x0
        self.method = method
        self.obj_func = obj_func
        self.params_ = None

    def loss(self, x, y):
        def loss_func(parameters):
            error = np.sum((y - self.obj_func(x)(parameters)) ** 2)
            return error
        return loss_func

    def fit(self, x, y):
        self._train_data = x
        self._train_target = y

        res = minimize(
            self.loss(x, y),
            self.x0,
            self.method
        )

        # res = self.optimizer
        if res.success:
            self.params_ = res.x
        return self
```

But after running it (sin_func is a function I defined):

```
cls = CLS_Estimator(obj_func = sin_func)
cls.fit(x1,y_train)
```

it gives me a type error:

**TypeError: loss_func() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.**

However, if I instance the loss() and run the minimizer by doing:

```
minimize(cls.loss(x1, y_train), x0 = [0.001]*4)
```

It worked,

I don't know what happened here. Can anyone help?

Comment: Providing the full error traceback, and a complete reproducible example, would make it a lot easier for prospective answerers to dig into the issue.